# How do i apply subdivision surface modifier while keeping deforms?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, subdivision-surface

i got a rigged mesh with a subdivision modifier thats after the armature modifier, that gave me deforms that look like this
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

is there a way i can preserve these deformations after applying the modifier?, only options i can think of is duplicating the mesh and using a data transfer modifier to transfer weights from the 2, or just redo weights entirely on these areas

Comment: why do you feel that it is necessary to apply the modifier? Modifiers provide a way of keeping to a non destructive workflow, and the ability to always go back to a previous state. Applying the modifier takes away that possibility.

Comment: reason why i want to apply the modifier is because i want to import this model into unreal engine, that way i make sure i got consistent weights and deforms on both sides

Comment: For the sake of the non-destructive workflow, at least consider saving a separate version of your file from before appying of the SubD modifier. As far as your issue goes, I find that in a similar project of my own, I get the same issue of the character's mesh taking on a different look after applying the modifier. I don't know why it does that or how to avoid it. The mesh just never looks the same prior to applying as it does after, no matter how high I set the detail for the viewport display in the modifier settings. I don't know why that is, either.